# Read Json inner node

Tags: c#, json

I have a json string in "**responseText**"

then I Deserialized that string using

```
var getJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
```

I get Josn like this
[My Json Output](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2bfc413c007837bb9fa9ea87b09efe16)

Now I want get country name from **0** > **address_components**.

I want to read that node which child node contain Types **country**

you can see

```
results > 0 > address_components > 8 > types > 0
```

Comment: @downvoter : Comment here.

Comment: You will require three for loop here, One for loop to iterate each results list and then inner for loop to iterate the address_components list for each result[i] to go over the each address_component and then again one more for loop to iterate over types list inside each address_component[j], here you check with if condition to type[k] that is it country or not.

Answer (score 4):

The result of `DeserializeObject` is a object. Best would be if it is a dynamic object. You can retrieve sub items like you would with an array or dictionary (depening what the json sub item is).

```
        dynamic receivedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

        var addresses = receivedData["results"][0]["address_components"];
        var firstAdress = addresses[0];
```

Also remember to name variables and functions correctly. getJson is not a good name because it does not retrieve the json. I would rename it to `retrievedData` or something.

Edit:
Use of dynamic, original example didn't work.

Comment: But my `retrievedData` is object type. so how can I write like this `retrievedData["results"]`

Comment: Tried it out, didn't work indeed. You should use dynamic. (.NET 4.0)

Comment: Or you could try out DeserializeAnonymousType

Comment: @RvdK In my case "address_components" has a different nodes also, if I want to get values from inside this node, how can i do it? is there any generic format ? becoz, these nodes may increase. Could you please edit your answer?